How to deal with $\forall M > 0$ in this limit?
For the limit $$\lim_{x\to +\infty} x^2+3 = +\infty$$ by definition we have that $\forall M > 0, \exists N > 0$ such that $\forall x > N$ we have $f(x) > M$.
But in this case then $\forall x > N$ we have $x^2 + 3 > M$ that is $x^2 > M - 3$ that is again $x > \sqrt{M - 3}$ and $x < -\sqrt{M-3}$. Considering the positive case, we have
$$x > \sqrt{M - 3}$$
But this is not true $\forall M > 0$, since for $M = 0$ or $M = 1$ or $M = 8/19$ the square root doesn't exist.
Then it should be $N_M = \sqrt{M-3}$ but things stopped working before this...
How should I reason with these types of limits/proofs?

You seem to be getting lost in the notation.  Think about what this is saying:  if you pick some value $M$, no matter how large that value of $M$ is, you can find some value $N$ (which might be huge, too), such that $f(x)$ is bigger than $M$ whenever $x$ is bigger than $N$.  In other words, by choosing $x$ "large enough", you can make $f(x)$ bigger than $M$.

For $M = 0$ (or any thing less than $3$) you can take $N = 0$.

So do things in order:  FIRST fix some value $M$, THEN find some value $N$ which is sufficiently large to ensure that $f(x)$ is bigger than $M$ for $x > N$.

So if $M = 0$, how large does $x$ need to be in order to ensure that $f(x) > M$?

@XanderHenderson I am a bit confused because our professor told us to start from "the resolution" that is $f(x) > M$ and from this to identify what $N$ is...

@XanderHenderson Since $f(x) = x^2+3$ then for every $x$ the function is always greater than zero. If then $M > 0$ then $f(x) > 0$ always, and $f(x) > M$ when $x > \sqrt{M-3}$ (?)

Okay, but you need to think about what you are doing, and what you want to do.  You have observed that if $M < 3$, you can't just take $N = \sqrt{M-3}$.  But so what?  In those cases, how large does $N$ have to be in order to ensure that $f(x) > M$?

@XanderHenderson I would say that I just need $N > 0$ (I was also thinking of $N > M$ but this would be wrong I believe)

We can also refer to an equivalent definition of limit $\forall M > M_0$ with $M_0$ sufficiently large in order to avoid these issues.

@user Thank you! I wasn't aware of that possibility, which indeed solves the problem

@J.N. I mean, what really matters are "large" values for $f(x)$ so these are useless details. What we really need is to show that inequality holds $\forall M > M_0$.

@user Indeed this makes the vision more clear to me. Simple and effective!

@J.N. Yes, indeed we can relax the definition without really compromise it.

@J.N. And similarly also for $\varepsilon - \delta$ definition.

Note that for what really matters, we can "relax" the definition without compromise it assuming the equivalent definition
$$\forall M > M_0, \exists N > 0\;\; \text{such that} \;\;\forall x > N \;\; \text{we have} \;\; f(x) > M$$
for an arbitrary and "sufficiently" large $M_0>0$ to avoid such kind of secondary issues.

If $0< M \le 3$ then in fact $M\le x^2+3$ for every $x\in\Bbb R$.  So for these choices of $M$ the choice of $N$ may be arbitrary.  For all other choices of $M$, your argument then works without issue.

For all $\,M>0\,$ you could choose $\,N_M=\sqrt M>0\,$ such that for any $\,x>N_M\,$ it results that
$f(x)=x^2+3>N_M^2+3=M+3>M\,.$
Hence, in this way we have proved that
$\forall M\!>\!0\;\;\exists N_M\!>\!0\;$ such that $\;\forall x\!>\!N_M\,$ we have $\;f(x)\!>\!M$
that is $\;\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\left(x^2+3\right)=+\infty\;.$
